# Display TextFile to listView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I am trying to display an opened textfile in textboxes and listViews. 
Every line on the textfile represents a value.

Here is what I have done now:

```
public void OpenFile()
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    string line = "";
    int index = 0;
    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(openFileDialog.FileName))
    {
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            index++;
            if (index == 1)
                InvoiceNumbertxt.Text = line;
            else if (index == 2)
                InvoiceDatetxt.Text = line;
            else if (index == 3)
                DueDatetxt.Text = line;
            else if (index == 4 || index == 5 || index == 6 || index == 7 || index == 8 || index == 9)
                PersonInfolst.Items.Add(line);
            else if (index == 10)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(index.ToString());
                Items.Add(new ItemProperties { 
                    Item = line, 
                    <<-- //Problem here. index is never 11.
                    Description = (index == 11) ? line : ""
                });
                itemlst.ItemsSource = Items;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

`index` is a convenient flag (variable) to insert the lines in order, and not overlap multiple lines into the same control.

Everything seems to work except that I can't figure out how to add different columns to the same row on the `listView`.

Normally when a user is adding different columns to the same row, the user uses something like this:

```
 Items.Add(new ItemProperties { 
      Item= "3", 
      Description = "Strong Bear", 
      Publisher = "Blizzard" 
});
```

All column are inside the same `ItemProperties` property so that they all are included to the same row.

I want to to achieve the same thing but I need to check `index` for each value added. So far everything worked perfectly but I can't increase the `index` inside the `else if` statement to add multiple columns to the same row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the file **is required** to contain at least those first 3 lines in order to be valid, what you can do is something that is easier:

```
public void OpenFile()
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() && File.Exists(openFileDialog.FileName))
    {
        // Read all the lines from the file and store them in an array.
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(openFileDialog.FileName);

        // Sanity check: there must be at least 3 lines.
        if (lines.Length < 3)
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Error: not enough lines in file: " + openFileDialog.FileName);
        else
        {
            InvoiceNumbertxt.Text = lines[0];
            InvoiceDatetxt.Text = lines[1];
            DueDatetxt.Text = lines[2];
            foreach (var l in lines.Skip(3).Take(6))
                PersonInfolst.Items.Add(l);    

            // I am assuming that the `ItemProperties` follow, as groups of 3 lines,
            // consisting of `Item`, `Description`, `Publisher`
            for (var i = 9; i + 2 < lines.Length; i += 3)
            {
                Items.Add(new ItemProperties { 
                    Item = lines[i],
                    Description = lines[i + 1],
                    Publisher = lines[i + 2]
                });
            }
            itemlst.ItemsSource = Items;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It can't recognize the `AddRange` in `PersonInfolst.Items.AddRange(lines.Skip(3).Take(6));` for some strange reason.

Comment: @John.P is `PersonInfolst` a `ListBox`, or something else? I updated the answer with an alternative way if it is not and its `Items` does not have an `AddRange` method.

Comment: `PersonInfolst` is a listbox, yes. Perhaps I forgot to implement a `using system`

Comment: Alright thanks. Only one last error:

`The name 'openFileDialog' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: I was using  `if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)` before in my code to browse a new file

Comment: @John.P updated, to include the previous parts of your `OpenFile` method.

Comment: I can now run the program without error and the program does display the data on the textboxes and on the `listbox` just like I wanted it, but not on the `listView`. See my updated question on how the application looks like.

Comment: I found the problem , you forgot to inlude `itemlst.ItemsSource = Items;` Thank you so much for you help. I really appreciate it!! :)

Comment: @John.P you are welcome, updated the answer to include that line. You may want to remove the image from your last edit of the question.